# To test following system of linear equation for equivalency

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let F be field of complex numbers I have two system of equations

$x_1  - x_2  =0 $

$2x_1 + x_2 =0$

And

$3x_1 + x_2 -0$

$x_1 + x_2 =0$

The definition says that each if equation in first system is a linear combination of system of equations for second system  ,then they are equivalent .How do i start this ?Hints ?

Thanks !

Comment: @Amzoti No we haven't reached there yet .How do i do with definition ?

Comment: What is your question? If you want to show if those two systems are equivalent, the standard way is to use row operations on each system to get a row reduced echelon form. If those forms are equal, the systems are equivalent; if not, they are not. Or is your question to find how each equation is a linear combination of equations in the second system?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes The Latter one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. Let the equations in the first system be $R_1$, $R_2$, and those in the second system be $S_1$, $S_2$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the multipliers for $R_1$, so that

$$R_1=aS_1+bS_2$$

Looking at the coordinates in the two systems, first for $x_1$ then for $x_2$, we get

$$3a+b=1$$
$$a+b=-1$$

Solve these simultaneous equations for $a$ and $b$ and you found the linear combination for $R_1$. Do similarly to find the linear combination for $R_2$ (using variables $c$ and $d$).

---

Here is a second way. As a half-way point, we name these equations:

$$e_1:\ 1x_1+0x_2=0$$
$$e_2:\ 0x_1+1x_2=0$$

Obviously we have

$$R_1=e_1-e_2$$
$$R_2=2e_1+e_2$$

You can use elementary row operations to get $e_1$ and $e_2$ in terms of $S_1$ and $S_2$. You will get

$$e_1=\frac 12S_1-\frac 12S_2$$
$$e_2=-\frac 12S_1+\frac 32S_2$$

Substitute the equations for the $e$'s into the equations for the $R$'s, simplify, and you are done.

---

Here is a third way that uses matrices. We can see that you are looking for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, as in my first method, such that

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1& -1\\ 2& 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}
\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3& 1\\ 1& 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

This is solved with

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 1& -1\\ 2& 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3& 1\\ 1& 1\\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: I know about AX=O ,how can i do this question using that thing

Answer (score 0):

Show that they have the same reduced row echelon form:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
for the first system and
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/3 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/3 \\
0 & 2/3
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/3 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
for the second system.

If $A$ and $B$ are the systems' matrices, you know that the reduced row echelon form for the first matrix is $U=FA$ for some invertible matrix $F$; similarly, the RREF of $B$ is $V=GB$ for an invertible matrix $G$. Since $U=V$, you have
$$
FA=GB
$$
which can be written as $B=(G^{-1}F)A$.

Note that this method is completely general and works for *every* linear system.